# Updating nested data in functional component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have the following data:

```
    const INITIAL_DATA = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name 1",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name 2",
    }
];
```

I'm setting the INITIAL_DATA with useState and also declare a new state variable with the first item of the data array.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(INITIAL_DATA);
const [single, setSingle] = useState(data[0]);
```

After choosing the single Data from a list:

```
{data.map(function (d, idx) {
  return (
   <li key={idx} onClick={() => handleOnClick(idx)}>
     {d.name}
   </li>
 )
})}
```

with the following handler:

```
const handleOnClick = (id) => {
  setSingle(data[id]);
}
```

the state variable single also fills a form with the "name" (single.name).
Now I try to update the form or the input field "name" and also update the dataSet with the new value but I'm stuck.

```
    const handleInputChange = e => {
    //const { name, value } = e.target
    //setValues({...values, [name]: value})
}
```

This is my input change handler. I'm managing to read the value but I'm stuck on how to update the nested array accordingly. I need to edit the array and update the data state variable with the new and updated array.

Comment: Is it possible to get a copy of what you have so far please

Comment: Sure, here's the slightly stripped component: https://pastebin.com/eHJSPAfL

Comment: So, you want to get the text value from the input and update the `data` array based on the state value of the current index. Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-einstein-26uco?file=/src/App.js) that might be a solution to your problem. Let me know if it is the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off the input needed to be controlled so by adding a text state you can update it with using `handleInputChange` and `setText`.

Next the `onSubmit` was not getting anything as the input was not `register` so `ref={register}` is added to the input to get the form data.

Next I took inspiration from the comment about using an ID in state to update the data array when submitting the form.

This is the updated file. Sorry my linter may have change some of the spacing a little

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import CollapseSection from '../components/UI/Collapse/CollapseSection'

import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

const Verbraucher = () => {
    const INITIAL_DATA = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Test 1",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Test 2",
        }
    ];
    const [data, setData] = useState(INITIAL_DATA);
    const [id, setId] = useState(0);
    const [text, setText] = useState(data[id].name);

    // For react forms
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (single) => {
      const d = [...data];
      d[id] = { ...single, name: single.name };
      setData(d);
    };

    const handleOnClick = (idx) => {
      setId(idx);
      setText(data[idx].name);
    }

    const handleInputChange = e => {
      const { value } = e.target;
      setText(value);
    }

    return (
        <CollapseSection
            title="Test"
            appear={true}
        >
            <Container className="sectionVerbraucher p-0 mb-3">
                <Row className="no-gutters">
                    <Col className="col" xs={12} md={6}>
                        <Row className="bg-white m-0">
                            <Col className="p-3" xs={12} md={12}>
                                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                                    <h1>Test</h1>
                                    <hr />
                                    <input
                                        ref={register}
                                        name="name"
                                        value={text}
                                        onChange={handleInputChange}
                                    />
                                    <input type="submit" />
                                </form>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>

                    <Col className="col colSummary bg-white p-3" xs={12} md={6}>
                        <ul className="listAll">
                            {data.map(function (d, idx) {
                                return (
                                    <li key={idx} onClick={() => handleOnClick(idx)}>
                                        {d.name}
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })}
                        </ul>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </CollapseSection>
    )
}

export default Data;
```